# Bulk replace products titles in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I would like to know if it is possible to bulk replace product titles in magento mysql database. I have 119 product titles that contain one piece that I want to replace with another ... is this possible? Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the DB, run:

```sql
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar v
JOIN eav_attribute e ON v.attribute_id = e.attribute_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 AND e.attribute_code = 'name' 
SET v.value = REPLACE(v.value, '{old}', '{new}');
```

If you're using flat catalog tables, you'll need to rebuild that index for your changes to take effect. To do that, in the admin, go to *System > Index Management*, check "Product Flat Data" and submit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have used this application and everything has come to perfection. Best regards!
Https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip